# monotouch: A better "drop-down"?

Tags: drop-down-menu, xamarin.ios

Is there any other way to have a drop down (like windows) rather than the huge wheel?

Comment: Even if you *could*, you shouldn't. That's what drop-downs look like on the iPhone, which means it's what all of your users are expecting. It's also done for pretty obvious reasons: can you imagine how difficult it would be to use a standard Windows-like drop-down combobox on an iPhone's touch screen? Apple pays these design engineers good money to think of these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option for choices that you see on the iPhone is to have another view slide in with the choices and a check next to one.  In that case, they are usually using a UITableView on the subpage.  You could make your own UIChoiceView based on that.

To see what it looks like, go to your Settings app on the phone and then choose Sounds and set your Ringtone.

Comment: Thanks Lou... I think your first suggestion is probably the way to go i I don't want it bounced on submission...